# can't set batched_key_access=on in optimizer_switch on mariadb 5.5

Tags: optimization, mariadb

I am switching my application from a Mysql5.6 to a Mariadb5.5. I am support to add batched_key_access=on in optimizer_switch, but when I do that, mariadb refuse to start :

```
170104 17:16:14 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
170104 17:16:25 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /data/mysqldata
170104 17:16:26 [ERROR] /data/mysql/bin/mysqld: Error while setting value 'batched_key_access=off' to 'optimizer_switch'
170104 17:16:26 [ERROR] Aborting
```

When I read Mariadb Docs, I am supposer to set mrr=on which is what I do :

```
optimizer_switch='index_condition_pushdown=off'
optimizer_switch='mrr=on'
optimizer_switch='mrr_cost_based=off'
optimizer_switch='batched_key_access=on'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It seems you are reading MySQL docs, not MariaDB. There is no `batched_key_access` key in MariaDB -- the functionality was developed in MariaDB 5.3, long before MySQL 5.6, so it naturally has its own naming, which MySQL didn't stick to while developing their version. What you might be looking for is `join_cache_bka`, but please read the [page about block-based algorithms](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/block-based-join-algorithms) in full, as you also need to choose a suitable value for `join_cache_level`, depending on your needs.

Comment: OK. I didn't saw that naming difference.
Thanks for your help

Comment: can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `batched_key_access` key in MariaDB -- the functionality was released in MariaDB 5.3, long before MySQL 5.6, so it naturally had its own naming, from which MySQL diverged. What you might be looking for is `join_cache_bka`, but please read the [page about block-based algorithms](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/block-based-join-algorithms) in full, as you also need to choose a suitable value for `join_cache_level`, depending on your needs.